# no se como resolver este error Undefined variable: _DATOS_EXCEL in C:\xampp\htdocs\kidv2\index.php on line 70

Tags: php

```
for ($i=2;$i<=$filas;$i++){
                    //$_DATOS_EXCEL[$i]['id'] = 1;

                    $_DATOS_EXCEL[$i]['nombre'] = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('A'.$i)->getCalculatedValue();
                    $_DATOS_EXCEL[$i]['fechainicio'] = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('B'.$i)->getCalculatedValue();
                    $_DATOS_EXCEL[$i]['horainicio']= $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('C'.$i)->getCalculatedValue();
                    $_DATOS_EXCEL[$i]['fechafinal']= $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('D'.$i)->getCalculatedValue();
                    $_DATOS_EXCEL[$i]['horafinal'] = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('E'.$i)->getCalculatedValue();

                }       
                $errores=0;


foreach($_DATOS_EXCEL as $campo => $valor){
     $sql = "INSERT INTO registro(id,nombre,fechainicio,horainicio,fechafinal,horafinal)  VALUES ('";
                    foreach ($valor as $campo2 => $valor2){
                        $campo2 == "activo" ? $sql.= $valor2."');" : $sql.= $valor2."','";
                    }

                    $result = mysqli_query($sql);
                    if (!$result){ echo "Error al insertar registro ".$campo;$errores+=1;}
                }
```

Comment: De donde viene la variable $_DATOS_EXCEL?

Answer (score 0):

Si la variable  `$_DATOS_EXCEL` no fue inicializada antes de usarla, intenta inicializarla como array o como array múltiple. `$_DATOS_EXEL  = array()`

Comment: muchas gracias es usted un maestro

Comment: De nada, suerte amigo.

Answer (score 0):

Debes iniciar la variable antes del bucle para que sea accesible fuera de este, independientemente de que le aportes contenido en el `for`.

```
$_DATOS_EXCEL = array();

for($i=2.....
```